# PagingItemReader vs CursorItemReader in Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch with multiple steps, some sequential and some parallel. Some of these steps involve fetching millions of rows and the query has multiple joins and left joins. I tried using JdbcPagingItemReader but the order by clause simply hangs the query. I don't get results even after 30 minutes of waiting. So I switched to JdbcCursorItemReader. 
Is that approach fine ? I understand that the JdbcCursorItemReader fetches all the data at once and writes it out based on the commit interval. Is there any option to specify to the reader to fetch, say, 50000 records at a time, so that my application and the system is not overloaded ?

---

Thank you for your response, Michael. I have 22 customized Item readers which are extended from jdbcCursorItemReader. If there are multiple threads, how would the Spring batch handle the resultset? Is there a possibility of multiple threads reading from the same resultset in this case, also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` has the ability to configure the fetchSize (how many records are returned from the db with each request), however that depends on your database and it's configuration.  For example, most databases you can configure the fetch size and it's honored.  However, MySql requires you set the fetch side to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in order to stream results.  Sqlite is another that has special requirements.

That being said, it is important to know that `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread safe (multiple threads would be reading from the same `ResultSet`).

I personally would advocate for tuning your query but assuming the above conditions, you should be able to use the `JdbcCursorItemReader` fine.